# Can't select layout in XPM

Tags: experience-manager, 2011-sp1

When using Experience Manager we ran into an issue that some people couldn't change the layout for the page or for the component presentation, when other people could.

First I thought it had to do with user right, since the people with the issues only had editor right (Folder, Structure Group, Component, Page and publish rights). But, even after making them Administrator they still couldn't change the layout.

The solution seemed to be to change the language to English (it was in Dutch).

Has anyone else encountered the same issue? Is there another solution?

Comment: Have you raised this with SDL support?